# Unit Testing Approach for an Algorithm in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am yet to jump into the TDD/BDD group. Trying to make the mental switch. For now I have been writing the business logic before my tests.

In one of my Rails model, I have a complex algorithm implemented. The implementation can be thought of as a couple of nested loops with lot of method calls from the same model.

Most of these methods take a complex hash created initially in the loop, modify it and pass it on to another method further in the loop which then processes it till we arrive at the final answer hash.

How should I go around unit testing my methods?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would suggest that you test the boundaries rather than the internal method calls.

Testing the inner workings of a class tend to lead to brittle tests that break even though the end result is what you want.

In this regard it would be best to test the input against the expected output and avoid testing how it got to the output.

There is an excellent talk by Sandi Metz on the subject here http://vimeo.com/48106365